# JavaScript + Ajax - How to camouflage IP address with Ajax of JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension, ip

I am developing Chrome Extension, and I need Ajax with JavaScript on that extension. I also need to camouflage a client's (Chrome Extension side) IP address with Ajax. Can I do it?

Comment: No, the only way to hide the IP is to use a proxy or VPN.

Comment: No, you can't. Chrome logic happens in "application layer", while IP address logic happens in "Network layer", which is much below the previous one.

Comment: I see. Thanks all.